# Sorting specific column in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I'm reading in lines from notepad.
When I sort them using sort function in visual basic, I notice that the result is not accurate.

```
For example 
hello i am who 1
I am who hello 14
am hello who I 13
```

I need to sort the fifth column, any idea how to do it in visual basic?

Comment: first off, is your fifth column always number, from your notepad ?
Second, those are several strings... so if your file is not large and you just want to sort the exact 5th character from each line, i suggest you put each of those word into a string array and sort it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this by parsing in the data from the text file as a list of tuples and then using orderby to sort by the fifth column, e.g.,:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        'I put this dialog here so you can browse to wherever your text file is
        Dim SelectFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog        
        Dim Result As DialogResult = SelectFileDialog.ShowDialog()

        If(Result <> DialogResult.OK)
            Exit Sub

        End If

        Dim FilePath As String = SelectFileDialog.FileName

        'read all the lines from the text file, store it in a string array
        Dim FileLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)

        'make a temporary list of tuples,                   (5th column, full line)
        Dim UnsortedLinesByFifthColumn As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String))

        For Each Line As String In FileLines

            'get the string on the fifth column of the line, it looks like your columns are delimited by spaces. 
            Dim FifthColumnString as String = Line.Split(" ")(4)

            'make a tuple representing each line, so we can sort it easily
            '                                             Item1              Item2
            Dim LineTuple As New Tuple(Of String, String)(FifthColumnString, Line)

            UnsortedLinesByFifthColumn.Add(LineTuple)
        Next

        'use OrderBy and a lambda expression to sort by the string in the fifth column
        Dim SortedLinesByFifthColumn As List(Of Tuple(Of String, String)) = UnsortedLinesByFifthColumn.OrderBy(Function(a) a.Item1).ToList()

        'print out the lines sorted by the fifth column
        For Each SortedLine As Tuple(Of String, String) In SortedLinesByFifthColumn
            Dim OriginalLine As String = SortedLine.Item2
            Console.WriteLine(OriginalLine)

        Next

        'stop the program so you can read what was printed to the console
        Stop

    End Sub

End Module
```

Input:

SomeTextFile.txt

```
hello i am who 1
I am who hello 14
am hello who I 13
```

Output (console)

```
hello i am who 1
am hello who I 13
I am who hello 14
```

Note that I'm assuming you want to sort the *lines* by the fifth *space delimited* column; if this isn't what you were asking please edit your question and I'll update this answer.